# Delete a line from imported text file string

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, carriage-return

I have imported two text files into my program-

```
f = open("words.txt","r")
words = f.read()
f = open("solved.txt","r")
solved = f.read()
```

and they are involved in a 'Guess the Word' game I am making.

At the end of the game, the program checks the users answers against the real ones...

```
print('Checking words...')
sleep(2)
if (words) == (solved):
    print('>Well done!')
    sleep(1)
    print('>All of your answers are right')

else:
    print('Not quite, keep trying!')
    sleep(1)
    menu()
```

The words text file has an extra carriage return on the end of the string, so no matter what the user makes the words string, it will never be exactly the same as the solved string (with no carriage return on the end), and therefore the user can NEVER win the game.

I HAVE the edit the text files within the program only, so I would like a way to delete the extra carriage return from the end of the words string, so that the user CAN win the game.

Words.txt-

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
Theres an extra space here
```

Solved.txt-

```
ACQUIRED
ALMANAC
INSULT
JOKE
HYMN
GAZELLE
AMAZON
EYEBROWS
AFFIX
VELLUM
```

-Alastair

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to modify the file, try to get the words into the program as a list.

Comment: `words = [w.strip() for w in f.readlines()]`

Answer (score 0):

```
def getwords(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        for word in file:
            word = word.strip()
            if word: yield word

words = list(getwords("words.txt"))
solved = list(getwords("solved.txt"))

... # do anything with 'words' and 'solved' #...
```

Comment: Just a quick question: Is using `for w in open(f)` as safe as using a `with`?